# Manage long press on UITextfiled without disabling context menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I've UITableView and its cell have one UITextField.

Now I added long gesture in UITextField but it not working. When I tap long gesture on textfield it always show context menu (select,copy cut,past,etc.).

**My question is that how to manage long gesture as well as context menu in UITextFiled.**

**I've tried below code:**

```
longGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
longGesture.delegate = self;

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %ld", indexPath.row);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer.state = %ld", gestureRecognizer.state);
    }
}
```

**Tableview delegate method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Note *obj = [self.dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    TableViewCell *Cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (Cell == nil) {

        Cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        Cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    else{
        Cell.memoField.text = obj.memoRowText;
    }

    Cell.memoField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [Cell.memoField addGestureRecognizer:longGesture];
    Cell.memoField.delegate = self;
    Cell.memoField.tag = indexPath.row;

    return Cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set up a failure requirement between the gesture that shows the context menu and your long press gesture. Specifically, you'll want the menu recognizer to require your long press to fail (i.e. you'll want the menu recognizer to wait until it has ruled out the long press). In code, one way to do that is this is implementing this delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)longPress shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)other {
    if (other.view /* is a text field in the table view */) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

These methods can be a little confusing.
Remember that you can add "static" failure requirements with `-[UIGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:]`, but in many cases you don't necessary easily have references to both recognizers (such as in this case).
In many cases, this suffices.
However, the gesture recognizer system also gives you a chance to install failure requirements "on the fly".

Returning YES from `-gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:` has the same effect as if you called `[second requireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:first]` (where `first` and `second` are the first and second arguments to that method).

OTOH returning YES from `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` has the same effect as if you called `[first requireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:second]`.